# Поиск изображений, содержащих бумагу с текстом

Tags: изображения, opencv, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, распознавание-образов

Имеется несколько фотографий. Необходимо найти среди них те фотографии, на которых запечатлен лист бумаги с текстом. Т.е. программа должна отделить фотографии книжных/тетрадных страниц от любых других фотографий (лиц, природы и т.д.). При этом выделить нужно только те фотографии, где бумага с текстом занимает бОльшую часть фото (например, фотография стены с приклеенным к ней маленьким объявлением нас не интересует, поэтому искать на изображении небольшие области с текстом не нужно).

С помощью каких технологий такое можно реализовать? Пока вижу варианты:

- OpenCV (много алгоритмов распознавания/детекции текста, но то, что я нашел, разработано для более общего случая, типа "поиск текста на фото" или "выделение областей с текстом")
- Нейронные сети

Не смог нагуглить чего-то конкретного под мою задачу, т.к., как я понял, обычно стоит задача поиска областей с текстом или распознавание символов, а мне это не требуется.

Если существуют какие-нибудь библиотеки для этого под C++/Java/Python, то это будет очень полезно.

Вот 2 примера искомых изображений и 1 пример неподходящего изображения.

[image: Пример искомого изображения]
[image: Пример искомого изображения]
[image: Пример неподходящего изображения]

Comment: Глубокие сверточные сети + tensorflow

Comment: На Ваш вопрос полноценный ответ дать сложно, покуда нет примеров изображений, количества данных, а также требуемой минимальной точности распознования. Также непонятно, коль скоро на бумаге нет текста, нужно ли относить данное изображению к  искомомуклассу.

Comment: Добавил примеры изображений, которые нужно выделить среди остальных. Для простоты можно считать, что изображений бумаги без текста не бывает (либо их можно отнести к любому классу, это неважно).

Comment: Наверно, можно для простоты считать, что если на изображении преобладает белый/светло-серый цвет, который является "фоном", на котором имеются "надписи" тёмным цветом, то это изображение относится к искомому классу.

Comment: Приведите примеры картинок, на которых нет текста. Т.е. которые относятся к противоположному классу.

Comment: Если бы Вы ещё ссыль на дамп дали, было бы вообще прекрасно.

Comment: Привел. Неподходящими фото будут обычные фотографии со смартфона среднестатистического человека, за исключением фотографий блокнотов, документов, тетрадей, страниц книг.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56961/discussion-between-anatoliysultanov-and-hedgehogues).

Comment: Нейронные сети тут, думаю, лишние. 
Если на тетрадном листе с текстом сделать дилатицию, то получим чистый белый лист. :-)  
Также можно  взять, например, 90-ю процентиль..

Answer (score 0):

Вот [пример алгоритма поиска текста](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html) на матлабе. Я бы вам посоветовал начать с него. Если у вас нет матлаба, можно то же самое сделать на OpenCV.

Это действительно более общий случай. Но если текст на светлом фоне, и занимает большую часть изображения, то возможно этого достаточно для ваших целей.

Answer (score 0):

1 Нейронные сети

2 Python

3 Обычная сверточная нс, даете в генератор папочку с 2 папочками: подходят/неподходят ьи все)